# How make a button in a child component trigger change event and update interface on owner component in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I have a child selection date component who uses ngModel to emit a change.

When I change date using the input the parent component is updated as expected.

I put two buttons for decrease and increase date, but they dont update the parent when clicked.

What I'm missing?

this is the component html pattern:

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="prevDate()">
    <mat-icon>arrow_back_ios</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-form-field>
    <input #inputData matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Escolha a data" [(ngModel)]="dataSel" (ngModelChange)="emitChangeEvent()">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<button mat-icon-button (click)="nextDate()">
    <mat-icon>arrow_forward_ios</mat-icon>
</button>
<button mat-icon-button (click)="emitChangeEvent()">
    <mat-icon>refresh</mat-icon>
</button>
```

and this is the typescript source code

```
    import { Component, OnInit,Input,Output,ViewChild,ElementRef,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { PainelService } from '../services/painel.service'
import '../date.extension'

@Component({
  selector: 'spp-seldata',
  templateUrl: './seldata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./seldata.component.css']
})
export class SeldataComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSel : Date;

  @ViewChild('inputData',{static:false}) inputData:ElementRef;
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter()

  constructor(public painelService: PainelService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSel = this.painelService.dataSel;
  }

  emitChangeEvent() {
    this.inputData.nativeElement.focus()
    this.painelService.dataSel = this.dataSel
    this.change.emit()
  }

  incDate(fator: number) {
    this.dataSel.setDate(this.dataSel.getDate()+fator);
    this.emitChangeEvent()
  }

  prevDate() {
    this.incDate(-1);
  }

  nextDate() {
    this.incDate(1);
  }

}
```

this is the insertion of the component in parent

```
<span style="float:right;" *ngIf="!hidedate">
    <spp-seldata (change)="changeDate()" #selData></spp-seldata>
</span>
```

and this is the event triggered by the component

```
changeDate() {
    this.painelService.getAllDataByDate()
}
```

Comment: if you create stackblitz demo for this, your question will get greater activity.

Comment: I put on stackblitz a sample of my problem and there it works. Do you believe? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wct8kg

Comment: are both angular versions same your local and stackblitz one?

Comment: I managed to solve, was related to a date checking problem... Thank you all!

Comment: If possible please do share your findings.

Comment: the problem was inside the incDate method

because inside painelService.getAllDataByDate() method I compared last checked date with the new one, to do not a additional useless processing. 

For decrement or increment a date I used: this.dataSel.setDate(this.dataSel.getDate()+fator) and this was messing around with dates, so, for some reason when I compared last date with the new one for angular nothing had changed, 

so when I changed to 

this.painelService.dataSel = moment(this.painelService.dataSel).add(fator,'days').toDate()

solved the problem